# I can't create a SharpDX solution in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, sharpdx

I have recently installed SharpDX and it's Visual Studio extension to create ShardDX solutions. I assume the template used by this extension would add dll dependencies and using statements and etc. But the solution is never created, I get this error when I try:

Unable to find SharpDX installation directory. Expecting [SharpDXSdkDir] environment variable

I googled it and the only result is part of the Visual Studio extension code itself, in a git repository:

https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX/blob/master/Source/VisualStudio/SharpDX.VisualStudio.Package/MainWizard.cs

The exact line of the Visual Studio Wizard that is throwing the error:

```
// Check that SharpDX is correctly installed
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SharpDXSdkDir")))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to find SharpDX installation directory. Expecting [SharpDXSdkDir] environment variable", "SharpDX Toolkit Wizard Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            throw new WizardCancelledException("Expecting [SharpDXSdkDir] environment variable");
        }
```

apparently, no one ever had this problem before. I tryed repairing my SharpDX installation but that did no good. Please help?

**additional information**: I use Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 and Windows 7. I had the SharpDXSdkDir variable already set before having this error (it's value is the installation folder of SharpDX: C:\Program Files (x86)\SharpDX). I tryed to create another variable, now a system variable instead of a user variable, with the same name and same value, and I still get the same error.

[off topic]: By the way, is SharpDX still an active project or has it been discontinued, like XNA? There is nothing on the website saying "we are discontinuing SharpDX" but still, their latest news is from 2013...

Comment: SharpDX is still very much active and is probably the most active DirectX project for the .NET Framework.

Comment: @Inisheer Those are very good news. How to I get in touch with the community? Their forum seems to be offline

Comment: Did you install the "Full Installer 2.5" from the sharpdx.org website?

Comment: You know, 2013 is so last year...

Comment: Yes, I did install the full installer. This is the name of the installer: SharpDX-Full-2.5.0.exe

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that the installation of SharpDX is not creating some environment variables it needs, you can try setting these variables yourself by going to Control Panel->System->Advanced System Configuration, there under Advanced Options look for Environment Variables, under system variables add the required variable (SharpDXSdkDir).

Unfortunately I don't use SharpDX, but you may try by looking for "setting the required variables for SharpDX".

Comment: It was already defined for my user. I then defined it at system level, with the same name and same value. I get the same error. Here's the line of the Wizard that's throwing the error:

I added the line of the Wizard that's throwing the error to my question

Answer (score 0):

That was a bug in the extension code. This is me reporting the issue to their development team: https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX/issues/311

Now all I need is a way to fix the extension. I have no idea how. Any help?